Modifying Spirograph pattern code using TikZ decoration
The following code from this answer
draws a spirograph pattern, using the TikZ decoration.
It results in making the peaks becoming more tapered, with scaling down.
Is it possible to maintain the same curvature and height of the peaks, with scaling down; instead of becoming more tapered.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\foreach[count=\c from 0] \mycolor in {blue, green!80!black, violet, brown!80!black, olive, orange, red, cyan}{  \xglobal\colorlet{color\c}{\mycolor}  }% define wanted number of colors, which are drawn anti-clockwise

\begin{document}

\newcommand\spiroglbl[4][]
{%
% Settings ==============================
% Filling : 1: yes, 0: no ==========================
\ifnum#2=0 %
\tikzset{FillStyle/.style={fill=none, line width=.2mm, line cap=round}}% if not filled
\else \tikzset{FillStyle/.style={line width=.1mm, line cap=round, fill=color\C!50, }}\fi % if filled
% Rotation direction (rotated peaks): 1: clockwise, 0: counter-clockwise ===
\pgfmathsetmacro\Sig{(-1)^(#3-1)}
% Rotation alternating (zigzag peaks): 1: yes, 0: no ==============
%  see below ....
% ========================================
% Input: =========================
\pgfmathsetmacro\n{32}% polygon sides % the peaks are drawn on the outside of the sides of an invisible 32-side polygon
% ============================
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[
HelpFigures/.style={draw=none},% draw=black % to draw the invisible 32-side polygon
]
\foreach[count=\R from 0% "rotation number"
] \r in {0.75,1,..., 2.00}{%% foreach 1 %
\pgfmathsetmacro\a{2*\r*sin(180/\n)}%  polygon side length
% segment length:
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\s{2cm*\a}%
% amplitude, if difference of two radii is 0.25 ===========
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\h{(  (\r+0.25)-\r*cos(180/\n) )*1cm-1.5*\pgflinewidth
}% ===================================
%
% ======================================
% rotation angle ====== (R = 0,1,2,3,...) ============
\ifnum#4=0 %
\pgfmathsetmacro\rotangle{\Sig*\R*0.5*360/\n}% rotation angle 1/2  (pos. rot. 
\else %
% alternative:  
\pgfmathsetmacro\rotangle{\Sig*mod(\R,2)*0.5*360/\n}% rotation angle 3/3 (alternating rot. sense)
\fi%
% =============================
% =============================
\foreach[
evaluate={\A=int(mod(\B,\n)+1)},% \A: start corner, \B: end corner
evaluate={\C=int(mod(\A,8))}% repeating color number
] \B in {1,...,\n}{%% foreach 2 %
%
% invisible polygon:
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=\n, HelpFigures,
minimum size=2cm*\r, rotate=\rotangle,
](pol) at (0,0) {};
%
% ===== begin insert number of peak, and a circle at the base of the peak  =====
%\draw[gray] (pol.corner \A) -- (pol.corner \B) node[midway, font=\tiny, sloped, above]{\B-\A}; 
%\draw[gray] circle[radius=\r];
% ===== end insert number of peak, and a circle at the base of the peak  =====
%
% spiroglbl as decoration: 
\draw[draw=color\C,
% old original code
%ultra thin, fill=color\C!50, 
%thick, fill=none, % alternative
% new:
FillStyle,
] decorate[decoration={
coil, aspect=0, 
segment length=\s, amplitude=\h,}
]{
(pol.corner \A) -- (pol.corner \B) 
\ifnum#2=1  -- cycle\fi
%node[midway, font=\tiny]{\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\rotangle}}
};
}%% end of foreach 2%
}%% end of foreach 1 %
\end{tikzpicture}
%\captionof{figure}{#1}% it needs \usepackage{capt-of}% optionally
}% end of command

\spiroglbl{0}{1}{1} %[not filled, clockwise \& alternating (zigzag)]

\spiroglbl{1}{1}{1} 
\spiroglbl{1}{0}{1} 
\spiroglbl{1}{0}{0} %[filled, counter-clockwise \& not alternating (rotated)]
\spiroglbl{1}{1}{0} 

\end{document}



It's unclear to me what this should look like in the end.

BTW: I think it has to be "\pgfmathsetmacro\Sig{(-1)^(#3-0)}", an early error of mine.

@cis. No it did only rotate the whole patterns. What I am asking for is for all the peaks to have the same shape, not to be tapered as they are scaled down. To look like this https://i.sstatic.net/pBHNnyYf.png

Set \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\h{<your constant value (e.g. 1.25mm) or your function of radius \r>}

@cis Making it (\r+.15) or any other value, changes the heights of all the peaks, but they still become tapered with scaling down.

Did you use sth. like \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\h{(\r+0.15)*1mm} with a length-value?

As mentioned in the comments, it is an  image like

desired.
This can be achieved with an appropriate setting of the amplituide of the decoration  (here coil, aspect=0); e.g.:
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\h{(\r+0.15)*1mm}

or similar; and then:
amplitude=\h



And as already mentioned in the comments, the code in the starting post still contains a small error from earlier versions:
Instead of \pgfmathsetmacro\Sig{(-1)^(#3-1)}
it has to be \pgfmathsetmacro\Sig{(-1)^(#3)}, otherwise clockwise and counterclockwise are swapped in the command \spiroglbl.
€dit: (\NewDocumentCommand) - old 
To make this whole thing more systematic, it could be usefull to use a command like this:
\NewDocumentCommand\Spiro{% 
  O{\CaptionText}% #1
    m% #2 <filled 1/0 ?>  
    m% #3 <clockwise 1/0 ?>
    m% #4  <alternating 1/0 ?>
  O{6}%     #5 number of circles (default: 6)
  O{32}%    #6 number of decorations (default: 32)
  O{8}%     #8 number repeating colors (default: 8)
  O{0.25}%  #8  equidistance of radii (default: 0.25)
  O{0.75}%  #9  start radius (default: 0.75)  
}{ ......
.......

then sth. like this
\begin{document}
\Spiro{0}{0}{0} 
\Spiro{1}{1}{0}[11][32][8][0.12][0.68]
\Spiro{1}{1}{0}[3][12][4][0.5][0.725]
\Spiro[my own text]{0}{1}{1}[11][20] 
\end{document}


Correction¹: #4 (not #3) for 'alternating'. 
Correction²: method for alternating colors added.
Correction³: document sizes adjusted.
%\documentclass[tikz, margin=5pt]{standalone}
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=11mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

% Define wanted number of colors
\foreach[count=\c from 0] \mycolor in {green!77!black, yellow, orange, red, blue, purple, cyan, magenta}{  \xglobal\colorlet{color\c}{\mycolor}  }

\begin{document}
\NewDocumentCommand\Spiro{% 
  O{\CaptionText}% #1
    m% #2 <filled 1/0 ?>  
    m% #3 <clockwise 1/0 ?>
    m% #4  <alternating 1/0 ?>
  O{6}%       #5 number of circles (default: 6)
  O{32}%     #6 number of decorations (default: 32)
  O{8}%      #8 number repeating colors  (default: 8)
  O{0.25}%  #8  equidistance of radii (default: 0.25)
  O{0.75}%  #9  start radius (default: 0.75)  
}{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Settings ==============================
% Filling  - 1: yes, 0: no ==========================
\ifnum#2=0 %
  \tikzset{FillStyle/.style={fill=none, thick}}%
   \def\FillText{unfilled}%
\else  \tikzset{FillStyle/.style={ultra thin, fill=color\C!50,}}%
          \def\FillText{filled}\fi
% Rotation Sense, direction - 1: clockwise, 0: countercolckwise ===
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\Sig{(-1)^(#3)}
\ifnum#3=1 \def\ClockText{clockwise}%
  \else \def\ClockText{counter-clockwise}\fi%
% Rotation Sense, alternating - 1: yes, 0: no ==============
%  see below ....
\ifnum#4=1 \def\AltText{alternating}%
  \else \def\AltText{not alternating}\fi%
% Caption ===================================
\def\CaptionText{\texttt{#5} circles with \texttt{#6} decorations; \\ 
in \texttt{#7} repeating colors; \\
with a radii-equidistance of \texttt{#8\,cm} \\
from a start-radius of \texttt{#9\,cm}; \\
with the settings: \\
\texttt{\FillText}, \texttt{\ClockText} \& \texttt{\AltText}%
}%
% ========================================
% Input: =========================
\pgfmathsetmacro\n{#6}% polygon sides (default: 32)
\pgfmathsetmacro\d{#8}% equidistance of radii (default: 0.25)
\pgfmathsetmacro\rStart{#9}% start radius (default: 0.75)
% ============================
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[
HelpFigures/.style={draw=none},% set draw=black, if needed
]
\foreach[count=\R from 0% "rotation number"
] \N in  {1,...,#5}{%% \N: "circle number"
%
\pgfmathsetmacro\r{\rStart+(\N-1)*\d}% radius
\pgfmathsetmacro\a{2*\r*sin(180/\n)}%  polygon side length
% segment length:
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\s{2cm*\a}%
% amplitude, if difference of two radii is 0.25 ===========
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\h{(  (\r+\d)-\r*cos(180/\n) )*1cm-1.5*\pgflinewidth
}
% ===================================
% ====================================
% rotation angle ====== (R = 0,1,2,3,...) ===========
\ifnum#4=0 %
\pgfmathsetmacro\rotangle{\Sig*\R*0.5*360/\n}% rotation angle 1/2  (pos. rot. 
\else %
% alternative:  
\pgfmathsetmacro\rotangle{\Sig*mod(\R,2)*0.5*360/\n}% rotation angle 3/3 (alternating rot. sense)
\fi%
% =============================
% =============================
\foreach[
evaluate={\A=int(mod(\B,\n)+1)},% \A: start corner, \B: end corner
evaluate={\C=int(mod(\A,#7))}% repeating color number
] \B in {1,...,\n}{%% foreach 2 %
%
% invisible polygon:
\node[local bounding box=spirograph, 
regular polygon, regular polygon sides=\n, HelpFigures, 
minimum size=2cm*\r, 
rotate=\rotangle,
](pol) at (0,0) {};
% Tests: =======================
%\draw[purple] (pol.corner \A) -- (pol.corner \B) node[midway, sloped, above]{\B-\A}; 
%\draw[] circle[radius=\r];
% =======================
% spiros as decoration: 
\draw[draw=color\C,
FillStyle,
] decorate[decoration={
coil, aspect=0, 
segment length=\s, amplitude=\h,}
]{
(pol.corner \A) -- (pol.corner \B) 
    \ifnum#2=1  -- cycle\fi
%node[midway, font=\tiny]{\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\rotangle}} % Test
};
}%% end of foreach 2%
}%% end of foreach 1 %
\node[anchor=north, yshift=-7mm, align=left] at (spirograph.south){#1};
\end{tikzpicture}
}%% end of command %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{tabular}{l l}
\Spiro{0}{0}{0} 
  & \Spiro{1}{1}{0}[11][32][8][0.12][0.68] \\
\Spiro{1}{1}{0}[3][12][4][0.5][0.725] 
  & \Spiro[my own text]{0}{1}{1}[11][20] 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}

€dit: (\pgfkeys) - new 
Because working with a command quickly becomes confusing with so many arguments; it is better to use a pgfkeys method which allows the convenient key-value syntax.
New: Addition of a colorlist={brown, blue, red,...}
In addition: The amplitude - in all of these codes - is basically defined as the distance between a n-th and a (n+1)-th polygon side. 
I added a pgfkey amplitude factor =<value (1: default)>; it should receive a value between 0 and 1.
Otherwise the whole design is a game with the values ​​start radius, radius distance and amplitude factor (all now pgfkeys).  
(If that is not enough, the drawing method must be [completely] changed.)
An overview:

An MWE:

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=11mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\usepackage{tkzexample}% for showing the code

% Spirograph ===========================
\newcounter{colorindex}% colorlist 1/6
\setcounter{colorindex}{-1}% colorlist 2/6  (default for color0, color1, color2,...)
\tikzset{SpiroSettings/.cd,
start radius/.initial=0.75,
radius distance/.initial=0.25,
number of circles/.initial=6,
number of decorations/.initial=32,
number of colors/.initial=8,
amplitude factor/.initial=1,
% filled 1/3 ==================
filled/.is choice,
  filled/.append code={\pgfkeyssetevalue{/tikz/SpiroSettings/filled}{#1}},
  filled/true/.style={/tikz/FillStyle/.style={fill=##1}},
  filled/false/.style={/tikz/FillStyle/.style={fill=none}},
  filled/.default=true, % filled ≙ filled = true
  filled=false, % initialize FillStyle and value
% clockwise 1/2 ==================
clockwise/.is choice,
  clockwise/.append code={\pgfkeyssetevalue{/tikz/SpiroSettings/clockwise}{#1}},
  clockwise/true/.code={\def\Sig{-1}},
  clockwise/false/.code={\def\Sig{1}},
  clockwise/.default=true, % clockwise ≙ clockwise = true
  clockwise=false, % initialize clockwise and value
% alternating 1/5 ==================
alternating/.is choice,
  alternating/.append code={\pgfkeyssetevalue{/tikz/SpiroSettings/alternating}{#1}},
  alternating/true/.code={\def\Alt{1}},
  alternating/false/.code={\def\Alt{0}},
  alternating/.default=true, % filled ≙ filled = true
  alternating=false, % initialize FillStyle and value
% colorlist 3/6 ====================
% written by @cfr --> https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/721338/56023
colorlist aux/.code={\stepcounter{colorindex}\colorlet{color\thecolorindex}{#1}},
colorlist/.code={\pgfqkeys{/tikz/SpiroSettings}{colorlist aux/.list={#1}}},
  colorlist/.list={green!77!black, yellow, red, orange, blue, purple, cyan, magenta, brown, black, pink, red, red, red,  red, red},% Default
%
% ============================
}
\def\mytrue{true}% alternating 2/5

\newcommand{\Spiro}[1][]{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setcounter{colorindex}{-1}% colorlist 4/6  (for color0, color1, color2,...)
\begin{tikzpicture}[SpiroSettings/.cd,#1]
\def\pkv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/SpiroSettings/##1}}%
%
\foreach[% foreach 1 %
count=\R from 0% "rotation number"
] \N in  {1,...,\pkv{number of circles}}{% \N: "circle number"
% number of polygon sides = number of decorations
\pgfmathsetmacro\n{\pkv{number of decorations}}
% disctance of radii
\pgfmathsetmacro\d{\pkv{radius distance}}
% radius
\pgfmathsetmacro\r{\pkv{start radius}+(\N-1)*\d}
% polygon side length
\pgfmathsetmacro\a{2*\r*sin(180/\n)}
% segment length:
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\s{2cm*\a}%
% amplitude
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\h{
\pkv{amplitude factor}*( (\r+\d)-\r*cos(180/\n) )*1cm
      -1.5*\pgflinewidth}% pgflinewidth-correction
% rotation angle 
\pgfmathsetmacro\rotangle{\Sig% clockwise 2/2 (\Sig = 1 or -1)
  *(\R^(1-\Alt))*(mod(\R,2)^\Alt)% alternating 3/5  (\Alt = 0 or 1)
   *0.5*360/\n}
%
\foreach[% foreach 2 %
evaluate={\A=int(mod(\B,\n)+1)},% \A: start corner, \B: end corner
% repeating color number:
evaluate={\C=int(mod(\B,\pkv{number of colors}))}% colorlist 5/6 
] \B in {1,...,\n}{%
% invisible polygon:
\node[local bounding box=spirograph, 
regular polygon, regular polygon sides=\n, draw=none,
minimum size=2cm*\r, 
rotate=\rotangle,
](pol) at (0,0) {};
%% Tests: =======================
%\draw[purple] (pol.corner \A) -- (pol.corner \B) node[midway, sloped, above, fomt=\tiny]{\B-\A}; 
%\draw[] circle[radius=\r];
%% =======================
%
% Needed if-then-keys for '--cycle' in the following:
\edef\mykey{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/SpiroSettings/filled}}% alternating 4/5
% spiros as decoration: 
\draw[draw=color\C, FillStyle=color\C!44,% colorlist 6/6
] decorate[decoration={
coil, aspect=0, 
segment length=\s, amplitude=\h,}
]{
(pol.corner \A) -- (pol.corner \B) 
    \ifx\mykey\mytrue --cycle\fi% alternating 5/5
%% Test =======================
%node[midway, font=\tiny]{
%\C% Colornumber
%%%%\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\rotangle}
%}
%% ==========================
};
}%% end of foreach 2%
}% end of foreach 1%
%
%  Info-Box (optional) ===========================
%\def\myinfos{%
%\textbf{\textbackslash myinfos:} \\
%filled: \pkv{filled} \\
%filled-macro: \UseName{if\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/SpiroSettings/filled}}yes\else no\fi \\
%clockwise: \pkv{clockwise} \\
%clockwise-macro: \textbackslash Sig = \Sig \\
%alternating: \pkv{alternating} \\
%alternating-macro: \textbackslash Alt = \Alt \\
%start radius: \pkv{start radius} \\
%radius distance: \pkv{radius distance} \\
%amplitude factor: \pkv{amplitude factor} \\
%number of circles: \pkv{number of circles} \\
%number of decorations: \pkv{number of decorations} \\
%number of colors: \pkv{number of colors} 
%}%
%\node[draw, align=left, anchor=north, yshift=-5mm] at (spirograph.south){\myinfos};
% ==============================
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%% end of command %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\begin{tkzexample}[overhang, latex=99mm, code=yellow!30]
% Default
\Spiro
\end{tkzexample}

\begin{tkzexample}[overhang, latex=99mm, code=yellow!30]
% Custom
% 'amplitude factor' changed

\Spiro[start radius=0.66, radius distance=0.12,
amplitude factor=0.65,
number of circles=10, number of decorations=28,
number of colors=7, 
alternating, filled, clockwise]
\end{tkzexample}

\begin{tkzexample}[overhang, latex=99mm, code=yellow!30]
% Example with a colorlist. 
% Note that 3 custom colors 
% and 1 default color are used.
\Spiro[colorlist={purple, purple, red},
number of colors=4,
start radius=0.725, radius distance=0.5,
number of circles=4, number of decorations=12,
alternating=false, 
filled, clockwise,
]
\end{tkzexample}

\begin{tkzexample}[overhang, latex=99mm, code=yellow!30]
% Custom

\Spiro[
number of circles=11, number of decorations=20,
number of colors=8, 
alternating, clockwise]
\end{tkzexample}
\end{document}


Thank you very much for your comments. I tried modifying the designated line to become ((\r+.15*\r*.45)), and (\r in {0.88,1,..., 2.00}) and I came up with the solution I posted. This solved the problem of making the peaks tapered with scaling down

See edit...............

Thank you very much for your time and concern.

Just one request please. Is it possible to progressively decrease the spaces between the rows by scaling down (i.e. not making them equidistance), to avoid the tapering effect of the peaks by scaling down. Thank you for your marvelous code.

See edit......................

Thank you very much. I appreciate very much your concern and time.

It is also an interesting and challenging task. So thanks from me too.

I tried the following code, which modified this line to become,
 \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\h{(  (\r+.15*\r*.45)-\r*cos(180/\n) )*1cm-1.5*\pgflinewidth

and this line to become
\r in {0.88,1,..., 2.00}

and it solved the problem (which is making the peaks the same shape, without they becoming tapered with scaling down) to a great extent.
resulting in the following pattern

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\foreach[count=\c from 0] \mycolor in {blue, green!80!black, violet, brown!80!black, olive, orange, red, cyan}{  \xglobal\colorlet{color\c}{\mycolor}  }% define wanted number of colors, which are drawn anti-clockwise

\begin{document}

\newcommand\spiroglbl[4][]
{%
% Settings ==============================
% Filling : 1: yes, 0: no ==========================
\ifnum#2=0 %
\tikzset{FillStyle/.style={fill=none, line width=.2mm, line cap=round}}% if not filled
\else \tikzset{FillStyle/.style={line width=.1mm, line cap=round, fill=color\C!50, }}\fi % if filled
% Rotation direction (rotated peaks): 1: clockwise, 0: anti-clockwise ===
\pgfmathsetmacro\Sig{(-1)^(#3-1)}
% Rotation alternating (zigzag peaks): 1: yes, 0: no ==============
%  see below ....
% ========================================
% Input: =========================
\pgfmathsetmacro\n{32}% polygon sides % the peaks are drawn on the outside of the sides of an invisible 32-side polygon
% ============================
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[
HelpFigures/.style={draw=none},% draw=black % to draw the invisible 32-side polygon
]
\foreach[count=\R from 0% "rotation number"
] \r in {0.88,1,..., 2.00}{%% foreach 1 %
\pgfmathsetmacro\a{2*\r*sin(180/\n)}%  polygon side length
% segment length:
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\s{2cm*\a}%
% amplitude, if difference of two radii is 0.25 ===========
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\h{(  (\r+.15*\r*.45)-\r*cos(180/\n) )*1cm-1.5*\pgflinewidth%(\r+.15) change the height of the peaks %(\r-.15) make the peaks grow to the inside instead of to the outside % (\r+.15)+\r makes the peaks very elongated
}% ===================================
%
% ======================================
% rotation angle ====== (R = 0,1,2,3,...) ============
\ifnum#4=0 %
\pgfmathsetmacro\rotangle{\Sig*\R*0.5*360/\n}% rotation angle 1/2  (pos. rot. 
\else %
% alternative:  
\pgfmathsetmacro\rotangle{\Sig*mod(\R,2)*0.5*360/\n}% rotation angle 3/3 (alternating rot. sense)
\fi%
% =============================
% =============================
\foreach[
evaluate={\A=int(mod(\B,\n)+1)},% \A: start corner, \B: end corner
evaluate={\C=int(mod(\A,8))}% repeating color number
] \B in {1,...,\n}{%% foreach 2 %
%
% invisible polygon:
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=\n, HelpFigures,
minimum size=2cm*\r, rotate=\rotangle,
](pol) at (0,0) {};
%
% ===== begin insert number of peak, and a circle at the base of the peak  =====
%\draw[gray] (pol.corner \A) -- (pol.corner \B) node[midway, font=\tiny, sloped, above]{\B-\A}; 
%\draw[gray] circle[radius=\r];
% ===== end insert number of peak, and a circle at the base of the peak  =====
%
% spiroglbl as decoration: 
\draw[draw=color\C,
% old original code
%ultra thin, fill=color\C!50, 
%thick, fill=none, % alternative
% new:
FillStyle,
] decorate[decoration={
coil, aspect=0, 
segment length=\s, amplitude=\h,}
]{
(pol.corner \A) -- (pol.corner \B) 
\ifnum#2=1  -- cycle\fi
%node[midway, font=\tiny]{\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\rotangle}}
};
}%% end of foreach 2%
}%% end of foreach 1 %
\end{tikzpicture}
%\captionof{figure}{#1}% it needs \usepackage{capt-of}% optionally
}% end of command

\spiroglbl{0}{1}{1} %[not filled, clockwise \& alternating (zigzag)]

\spiroglbl{1}{1}{1} 
\spiroglbl{1}{0}{1} 
\spiroglbl{1}{0}{0} %[filled, anti-clockwise \& not alternating (rotated)]
\spiroglbl{1}{1}{0} 

\end{document}

